# unabled to use gnucash with mysql

Tags: 14.04

I use GNUCASH on windows, and this got the possibility to use mysql.
Can I use GNUCASH on ubuntu with mysql connection, because I don't have that option now on ubuntu. And I like ubuntu very much

I use ubuntu 14.04 and GNUCASH 1:2.6.1-2

Comment: What does mysql do?

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the libdbd-mysql package by executing the following command in a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-mysql
```

Or you can find this package in the gnucash recommended packages.

Comment: Кирилл, you're answering a 16 reputation user, so (unlike you) he might not know what a terminal is, or how to execute a command in a terminal...  ;-) Probably not looking at the question, but I've had users who don't know the difference between a space and a dot... :(

Comment: @Fabby, 
i understand you. And thanks for the correction of the response.